# How to plot smaller polygons at the sides of a bigger polygon?

Tags: matlab, polygon, fractals

I am not well versed in MATLAB however I need to use it to complete a project, I need to write a code which creates a big polygon and "n" small polygons , where "n" is the number of sided the big polygon has and then displays the plot with the big polygon in the centre and each small polygons along each sides of big polygon . So far I have managed to create the big polygon. would appreciate any help further. I have attached my code below, and the expected output . I did try to create an array to store the 'n' small polygons however I am not sure if that's how MATLAB works.

My code so far

```
n=input("enter number of polygon sides: ")
scalefactor=input("enter scale factor:")
parentpoly = nsidedpoly(n,'Center',[5 5],'SideLength',5);

for(i=1:n)
    childpoly(i)=scale(parentpoly,0.25);
end
```

What I am getting:

[image: My case the smaller polygons are overlapping]

Expected Output:

[image: OutputImage]

Comment: How do you position the small polygons with respect to the big polygon? Is there a fixed distance between the center, etc.? Also, the expect output has the squares rotated compared with your current output, it that important?

Comment: The rotation isn't important the distance isn't fixed it's like plotting the first layer of fractals, so the distance would depend on the number of sides a polygon has, so 4 squares equidistant on each side of a big square, 3 triangles equidistant from each side of a triangle.

Comment: And how do you define the distance?

Comment: That is the point I am struggling withI managed to create n smaller polygons for a n sided polygon but I can't place the smaller polygons in each side of the larger polygon